# how to display nested options within a combo box

Tags: forms, input-fields, combobox

If there are a lot of options to choose one from within a single combo box, what's the best way to do it?

here's an example of the structure

answer category 1
- answer 1
- answer 2
- answer 3
answer category 2
- answer 1
- answer 2
- answer 3
.
.
.

**solution 1**
Simply indenting them within a combo box would be a logical way but extremely long combo boxes aren't user friendly.

**solution 2**
Split into 2 combo boxes and the 2nd combo box would populate based on the answer category chosen in the 1st combox box

**solution 3**
Came across this solution, which seens quite intuitive, however it's unconventional. 
[image]

which would be the best solution for this?

Comment: How deep will you want to go? Also, Is the combo box the right choice then?

Comment: @Stacked just 2 levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Your second set of options optional,As you are asking lot of information to user,current option which you have shown may work functionally but it is not intuitive and will not support normal user behavior.

**Analysis Paralysis**
Analysis paralysis or paralysis by analysis is the state of over-analyzing (or over-thinking) a situation so that a decision or action is never taken, in effect paralyzing the outcome.

[image]